# How can I copy a print file to a networked printer?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, printing, ip

I have an Epson TM-T88V network printer. I can print to it using the printer driver. But I need to copy a "print file" to the printer using the command line, and this causes problems.

I cannot use

```
copy file.prn {ip-address}
```

Because this will simply copy the file to a new file with the name of the ip address.

I have seen various suggestions... that do not seem to work:

```
copy file.prn \\{ip-address}
```

> *The specified path is invalid*

This one too failed me:

```
NET USE LPT1: \\{ip-address}\{printer-name}
```

> *System error 66 has occurred.*
>
> *The network resource type is not correct.*

Trying to ftp the file over failed, too. (Could not open a connection.)

Any ideas how to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Microsoft's `lpr` client

```
C:\>lpr /?

Sends a print job to a network printer

Usage: lpr -S server -P printer [-C class] [-J job] [-o option] [-x] [-d] filename

Options:
     -S server    Name or ipaddress of the host providing lpd service
     -P printer   Name of the print queue
     -C class     Job classification for use on the burst page
     -J job       Job name to print on the burst page
     -o option    Indicates type of the file (by default assumes a text file)
                  Use "-o l" for binary (e.g. postscript) files
     -x           Compatibility with SunOS 4.1.x and prior
     -d           Send data file first
```

This works with JetDirect and similar boxes/adapters as well as Unix/Linux and Windows servers that have the LPD service enabled.

Comment: lpr did the trick! Mind you, I had to do do gymnastics to get it to work on a 64-bit Windows installation. http://superuser.com/a/420410/2565

Answer (score 5):

From the command prompt:

```
copy filename \\Server Name\\{Printer Share Name}
```

If there is a space with the print share name be sure to enclose in quotes. For example:

```
copy filename "\\{Server Name}\\{Printer Share Name}"
```

Comment: I'm getting "Access is denied. 0 file(s) copied" when I try this on Win10, even in an admin command prompt.

Answer (score 4):

lpr works great on Win 7 and up. You do not need to copy it. In Control Panel, go to "turn windows features on or off" and make sure "print and document services" are installed.

To use lpr to send a file to printer that uses the RAW protocol, the syntax is:

```
lpr -S <printer name or IP> -P raw <file to send>

e.g.
lpr -S 192.168.11.118 -P raw postscript.ps
```

[image]

Comment: How would you specify the port of that ip address?

Comment: @Superdooperhero  The -P option lets you specify the printer/port. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/lpq

Answer (score 2):

Try sharing the local printer connection and then connect it to LPT1

```
NET USE LPT1: \\localhost\printer
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. The net use command was successful. However, trying to copy it afterwards failed. ('copy file to lpt1' gave 'access is denied', and 'copy file to lpt1:' gave '"lpt1:" is not a recognized device. The system cannot find the file specified.')

Comment: If you use `/persistent:yes` it will keep the connection after a reboot `NET USE LPT1: \\localhost\printer /persistent:yes`

Comment: in my experience, the above works great on win XP and win 7, but not on Win 10

Answer (score 1):

```
copy /b file.prn \\Server\PrinterName
```

i just tested and it works for me

Answer (score 1):

After lot of searching, if you want to print over network or local.

1. Make sure the printer is shared.
2. Print:

a. to network:

For example:

```
COPY out.ps "\\192.168.11.12\\HP LaserJet"
```

b. to local printer:

```
COPY out.ps "\\localhost\\CutePDF Writer"
```

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Answer (score 0):

Just share the folder c:\windows\system32\spool\printers in which the shared printer is connected for everyone with full control both in share and security menu. That will work fine.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.