# Print using lpr command in 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, printing

I need to use the lpr command to [copy a print file directly to a network printer](https://superuser.com/questions/420149/how-can-i-copy-a-print-file-to-a-networked-printer/420379#420379). However, the lpr command does not seem to be included in 64-bit editions of Windows.

What can be done to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a [list of Windows commands](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/a/command-availability.htm) at about.com

```
Command     MS-DOS  Win 98  Win XP  Win Vista  Win 7
Lpr         N       Y       Y       Y²         Y²
```

> [1] This command is not available in 64-bit versions of this operating
>   system.
>
> [2] This command is only available in this version of Windows when LPD
>   Print Service is turned on from Windows Features.

The omissions of a 1 superscript after the Y suggests `lpr` can be made available by enabling the "LPR Port Monitor" using "Control Panel/Programs and Features/Turn Windows features on or off".

Answer (score 6):

lpr works great on Win 7 and up. You do not need to copy it. In Control Panel, go to "turn windows features on or off" and make sure "print and document services" are installed.

To use lpr to send a file to printer that uses the RAW protocol, the syntax is:

```
lpr -S <printer name or IP> -P raw <file to send>

e.g.
lpr -S 192.168.11.118 -P raw postscript.ps
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By copying the lpr* files from C:\Windows\System32 on a 32-bit Windows machine, I was able to successfully run the lpr command on a 64-bit Windows machine.

I am hoping there is a better way, though...

Answer (score 0):

*Windows 10*

- https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/connect-network-printer-lpr-windows10
- 64 bit https://ninefile.com/ccow6wzr8zfr.html
- 32 bit https://ninefile.com/zspan21o028i.html

*Windows 7*

- 64 bit https://ninefile.com/ano5x31redrz.html
- 32 bit https://ninefile.com/23f6m7lwh1ku.html