# Using Dataflex in the DOS environment of Windows7

Tags: windows-7, printer

For many years we have been using Dataflex Data Base software as our "Company System" on our NT network.  It is run by all 8 users running 'XP' and invoking the DOS environment running in "XP".   Run perfectly well.   Prints to our 2x big Ricoh network printers and local printers too.    Dataflex creates a file to one of the network drives and appends .....  APPEND ALLCOMM "copy " allpath " LPT2"  ... for example ..

Finally ... RUNPROGRAM WAIT ALLCOMM.   This has printed exactly for many years.    We have 3 computers now running Windws7 and not one of them will print to a neteork printer.   The DOS setup is the same,  everything on the screen runs perfectly.  The print command from the screen is the same (as shown above).   Exeduting the COPY command in the DOS window using the same string created by Dataflex sends the files off the the printer fine.

It appears that the COPY command is not being executed by PowerFlex's command " RUNPROGRAM WAIT ALLCOMM ".  but it has done so for years and still is doing so with all the machines running the same DOS window inside  "XP".

We thought it had to be setting up the printers,  but executing the COPY command from the network folder works and executing it from PowerFlex doesn't.  I hope you experts can advise what is different with the W7.

Thanks and regards

Bernard

Comment: If you can modify the commands then this would be a duplicate of [How can I copy a print file to a networked printer?](http://superuser.com/questions/420149/how-can-i-copy-a-print-file-to-a-networked-printer) Also see `net use ` commands [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314499) which should help even in Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be set up using LPT2 as the port for the printer, so we may assume that RUNPROGRAM uses the same port to send the file to the printer. In that case you should be able to use the NET USE command, to map a network printer to an LPT port, as follows:

NET USER LPT2: //servername/printername /PERSISTENT:YES

In this command servername is the name of the server that the printer is set up on; printername is the share name of that printer, as set on the server.