# Ghostscript with mswinpr2 is slow, how to make it faster?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printing, printer, ghostscript

I'm using the following command to print a pdf file.

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64c.exe" \
       -dBATCH \
       -dNOPAUSE \
       -dFitPage \
       -c "mark /OutputFile (%printer%PrinterName) /UserSettings <</DocumentName (myFile.pdf)>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice" -f myFile.pdf
```

The printing is very slow. `myFile.pdf` has about 1000 pages. I heard that it is because `mswinpr2` driver. We have in a company about 10 printers. How can I recognize what to write instead of `mswinpr2` to print faster? The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: (1) Try to add `-dNOTRANSPARENCY` to avoid printing the page as an image (if the PDF uses transparency). (2) Try to lower the resolution, for example `-r300`. (3) Your print command may be overly complicated, why not just do `gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="%printer%\\printServer\printerNameWith Spaces" myFile.pdf`.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you, I will try it. Doesn't it lower quality? We have really good-quality printers, so why don't to change the device? Do you know how to find out what device to use? But I will try your recommendation. Overcomplited? That's because there is a need for DocumentName in the printer spooler, that's all.

Comment: Please [see](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/Devices.htm#PDF) 10.2. And I don't see `-dNOTRANSPARENCY` in the documentation.

Comment: @harrymc The speed is only a little better.

Comment: Do you have lots of images in the document?

Comment: @harrymc Not much images. We noticed one thing yet, that sPAPERSIZE=a4 switch is ignored.

Comment: It is ignored perhaps because of `-dFitPage`. You will find `-dNOTRANSPARENCY` in the [documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm). What did you do that improved the speed a bit?

Comment: removing `dFitPage` didn't help it. `dNOTRANSPARENCY` speeded it a bit.

Comment: Is the printer connected by USB, Ethernet or WiFi? Check the advice in *How to Use Ghostscript* section [Improving performance](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Improving_performance).

Comment: @harrymc ethernet

Comment: Two more switched that might help: `-dInterpolateControl=0` and `-dNumRenderingThreads=4`.

Comment: Have you tried these switches?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I tried but it's still slow.

Comment: Not even a bit faster?

Comment: @harrymc Almost unrecognizable, it's strange.

Comment: What is strange?

Comment: @harrymc that the switches looks like being ignored. I also bountied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348864/how-to-change-ghostscript-output-file-in-printer-spooler) issue

Comment: Please see added answer, and post additional info on the file you are trying to print.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I'm sorry, the files are printed in other departmant and the lady which is printing is often very busy, so it's difficult to test. The documents contain often personal data, so I can't post it.

Comment: Ok, feel free to ask whenever you have any additional info.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The usual advice for speeding up GhostScript printing is to use the switches of
`-dNOTRANSPARENCY`, `-dInterpolateControl=0` and `-dNumRenderingThreads=4`.

In your case, only `-dNOTRANSPARENCY` gave a slight improvement, so you are
using just a few images that can benefit from this optimization.

I think you have reached the limit of what is possible with GhostScript,
so it might be time to try another product.

For example, I use
[Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/)
which is much faster.

To print silently the document with the default printer:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /p <PDF Path>
```

To print the document with a designated printer:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /t <PDF Path> [Printer]
```

If you get the same speed with Foxit as with GhostScript, then the problem
might be with the speed of the Ethernet connection to the printer.
Try to connect to the printer using cable to verify this possibility.

Comment: When the document is printed from Acrobat Reader, it's fast, so Ethernet should not be the problem. Does the FoxitReader show file name in the printer spooler?

Comment: Foxit reader is not free software.

Comment: Certainly it is - I'm using it.

Comment: If GhostScript is the problem, there are other such products than Foxit Reader. This is just the product I know best.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: It is hard to give a precise answer without knowing what/where you are trying to print. Accordingly, all the testing proposed takes time.**

You have to check first what are your margins for speeding up.
Generally speaking, you might have reached a speed limit with your resources.

Possible causes (and possibly jointly affecting behaviour; [this](https://superuser.com/a/1539551/245595) already mentioned 2 and 3):

1. The file you are printing. Compare with other files so you see if this is the culprit, and what part of it.
   See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834038/slow-ghostscript-conversion-and-slow-printing-with-large-ps-files).

   1.1. What is the file size?

   1.2. Does it have a lot of pictures? (you commented it does not)

   1.3. Are those few pictures heavy? Can you reduce their size?

   1.4. Does another file with 1000 pages of only text print faster?
2. The printing program

   2.1. You may try `pdftops` and then printing the PS file.
   See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21913333/2707864).

   2.2. You may try copying the file to the print queue.
   See [How can I copy a print file to a networked printer?](https://superuser.com/questions/420149/how-can-i-copy-a-print-file-to-a-networked-printer)
3. Flags for Ghostscript
4. The printer / driver.
   Is it PS-compatible?

   4.1. You may try intercepting the spool file (to check what happens and perhaps solve your problem), see [this](https://typehaus.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207444723-How-do-I-capture-a-spool-file-from-a-Windows-print-queue-).

As for the paper size, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61078286/2707864).